# Cannot get handle of Edit control from notepad using Windows 11

Tags: c#, .net, notepad, user32, editcontrol

I have several ways to get notepad's edit control handle:

1. Using user32

```
FindWindowEx(ForegroundHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null);
```

2. Using Automation

```
var notepadWindow = AutomationElement.FromHandle(ForegroundHandle);

var editControl = notepadWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children,
                new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "Edit"));
```

This 2 ways perfectly work using Windows 10 but when it comes to Windows 11 it's not working, none of them.

I am expecting this should work with Windows 11 in the same ways as it is with Windows 10.
During invetigation I have found article about preview build: https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2022/10/27/announcing-windows-11-insider-preview-build-25231/ where it states:

> Fixed a rare issue where FindWindow and FindWindowEx might return an unexpected window.

But I am not sure that this is relates to my problem, because I am returning **IntPtr.Zero** or **null** all the time using approaches above.

**UPDATE**

I found what is the problem, instead of using "Edit" in FindWindowEx, you need to use "RichEditD2DPT" for Notepad in Windows 11

```
var notepadTextBoxHandle= _winApiService.FindWindowEx(NotepadForegroundHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "NotepadTextBox", null);

if (notepadTextBoxHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    _editControl = _winApiService.FindWindowEx(NotepadForegroundHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "RichEditD2DPT", null);
}
```

Comment: It would help to know where you got `ForegroundHandle` from and whether you've verified that it is indeed a handle to the window you think it is.

Comment: From https://devblogs.microsoft.com/math-in-office/windows-11-notepad/ "The new Windows 11 Notepad uses RichEdit" which probably means you're looking for the wrong thing.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I tried your suggestion a moment ago, it did not work

Comment: [Spy++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment?view=vs-2022) us your friend. If you read the first article I linked they are not using a standard RichEdit control.

Comment: @RetiredNinja When I am using Spy++ tool, it does not show any data when navigating on notepad edit area

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am getting it from GetForegroundWindow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getforegroundwindow